# What exactly a session inside the TCP connection is?

Tags: session, tcp, connection

When I type google.com in a single browser tab, a TCP connection is eshtablished that is uniquely identified by the 2 sockets.

But what exactly a TCP session here is?

A lot of websites claim that a session is collection of multiple transactions that occur between server and client inside the same connection.

If true, what is a transaction.

My second question is, what exactly the session stores and how much memory does it require?

**My understanding about a transaction (which may be wrong. If wrong then please correct me):**

When a connection is eshtablished to browse the google.com, in addition to GET request for the main page, there are also other GET and POST requests to fetch resources like images or other stuffs.

Can these "other" requests be considered as an individual transactions?

As per **@Steffen Ullrich**'s comment, I am posting an image of AMQP protocol terminology:

[image]

In this image, you will find the definition of the session -  ***bi-directional channel inside the connection***

**References:**

1. The above image is taken from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3e9lDlMn5M

Comment: *"A lot of websites claim ...."* - please provide the relevant references, since they might talk about different things. Session is a very generic term and a TCP session is different from a HTTP level session is different from a TLS session ... So if you ask about *"session __inside__ TCP connection"* it is not clear what you mean in the first place: the TCP connection is exactly the TCP session. HTTP sessions are orthogonal to the concept of TCP session, i.e. multiple HTTP sessions might be inside a single TCP connection and a single HTTP session can span multiple TCP connections etc.

Comment: The example you provide is about AMQP sessions, which again is different from TCP sessions. Like I said, *session* is a very generic term and the meaning depends on the specific context. As to what AMQP sessions are - see [the definition in the standard](https://docs.oasis-open.org/amqp/core/v1.0/os/amqp-core-transport-v1.0-os.html#section-sessions).

Answer (score 0):

This is my understanding,

When connection is established that connection can be persistent or non persistent depending on http version, headers and browser. If it's persistent connection browser will use same TCP connection to send those other requests as well.

Yes, each http request and response would be considered one transaction and in single persistent TCP connection many such transactions can happen.

To understand more about connection persistence I would recommend this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Connection_management_in_HTTP_1.x

Answering to other questions:

TCP session is whatever happens from initiating a TCP connection, request response exchange and closing connection.

And talking about memory I guess it would be internal data structure to store connection information and read and write buffers.

Answer (score 0):

As per the TCP standard, the so called "TCP Session" does not exist at all. There exists only the TCP Connection. Do not confuse it with the AMQP Session.

The AMQP Session is defined in [OASIS Advanced Message Queuing Protocol (AMQP) Version 1.0](https://docs.oasis-open.org/amqp/core/v1.0/os/amqp-core-transport-v1.0-os.html#section-sessions) standard.